# Using Docker to chown a container directory (ubuntu - mysql/mysql-server)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to instantiate a mysql container with a /var/lib/mysql/ directory with proper permissions and ownership for COPY binding the sql dumps from my old mysql server. But with /var/lib/mysql/ having its permissions and ownership as-is, the container exits upon mount. So I am trying to alter the permissions and ownership of this directory upon instantiation of the container. But this is proving difficult ...

#### Target: rwxr-xr-x mysql:root /var/lib/mysql

#### Configuration:

1. Dockerfile:
   FROM mysql/mysql-server
   RUN chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
   RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/
2. Images:
   REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
   wat                  1.0                 09edc2e9d91d        About an hour ago   381MB

   mysql/mysql-server   latest              716286be47c6        2 months ago        381MB
3. docker-compose.yml:
   version: "3"
   services:
   mysqlmysql-server:
   image: wat:1.0
   container_name: mysqlmysql-server

### Processing ...

$ `docker ps`
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                 NAMES
b21339cf2986        wat:1.0             "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysqlmysql-server

b21339cf2986# `ls /var/lib -al | grep -e mysql$`
drwxr-x--- 7 mysql mysql 4096 Jun 27 04:06 mysql

### This is wrong. I am expecting at least rwxr-xr-x and/or mysql:root by now

### Teardown / Square 1 ##

$ sudo docker stop *; sudo docker rm *; sudo docker image rmi *; sudo docker pull mysql/mysql-server
$ sudo docker build --tag wat:1.0 - < mysqlmysql-server/Dockerfile-mysqlmysql-server
Successfully built 2a38f54299d8 
Successfully tagged wat:1.0 
$ `sudo docker images`
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
wat                  1.0                 2a38f54299d8        About a minute ago   381MB
mysql/mysql-server   latest              716286be47c6        2 months ago         381MB

$ `sudo docker-compose up -d`
$ `sudo docker ps`
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                    PORTS                 NAMES
b94f9e776d78        wat:1.0             "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   About a minute ago   Up 59 seconds (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysqlmysql-server

$ `sudo docker exec -it b94f9e776d78 bash`
bash-4.2# ls /var/lib -al | grep -e ql$
drwxr-x--- 6 mysql mysql 4096 Jun 27 04:27 mysql

#### The above is WRONG

#### Target: rwxr-xr-x mysql:root /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 3):

The Docker Hub `mysql/mysql-server` image [declares a `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile#L31).  That means that [subsequent Dockerfile steps can't make any further changes to that directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes).

In practice you will almost always mount your own storage on that directory.  When you do that the contents and permissions of that storage (either a host directory or a Docker named volume) will hide anything that the Dockerfile does.  The [Docker Hub `mysql` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) has instructions for "Running as an arbitrary user" which will let you run the container with a user ID matching a host directory's owner; those instructions may or may not work for the alternate image you're using.